# Disadvantages of Array.protoype.every over Array.prototype.forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Both methods iterate over the current array's elements but only Array.prototype.every allows you to break out of the loop similar to how you can use `break` to exit a for-loop.

When looking at [browser compatibility matrixes](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.every) both seem to be supported by the same browsers.

Are there any disadvantages (performance, readability, ...) to `Array.prototype.every` compared to forEach that I have missed or why isn't `every` more common?

Main main point here is that most of the times I want to use forEach as a replacement for the classic for-loop for the sake of readability, but given that there is no way to break out of a for-each loop, every appears to be more more an equivalent here. The option to use `every` for that has been mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: _The [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function_ <-> _The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method executes a provided function once per array element._

Comment: They are not really the same, `every()` returns true if the condition is met for all elements while `forEach()` executes a function for each element

Comment: Sure, but both can be used to iterate over every element the array.

Comment: @Andreas, adeneo the OP already mentioned that in the question as desirable behavior.

Comment: `filter` and `map` can be used to iterate over an array as well, but it's not really how they were intended to be used.

Comment: @adeneo: They don't offer you ways to break out of the loop and are not suggested as alternatives on various sources like MDN ...

Comment: If you're going to break out, there's `some()`, which is intended for that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/26Z6A/

Comment: I've updated the original question to clear up what I'm asking since I apparently failed to communicate my intentions in the first paragraphs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between .map, .every, and .forEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340893/what-is-the-difference-between-map-every-and-foreach)

Comment: @Phil: I checked that post before but I'm more asking about disadvantages of using one over the other, so I don't believe them to be duplicates.

Comment: There's a reason it's called `forEach`, and not `forSome`, it iterates over all the elements, if you don't want to iterate over all the elements, use one of the other methods, most likely `some()`, or a regular for loop.

Comment: @adeneo: You realize that I'm asking about "disadvantages", right? ;-)

Comment: Yes, and the disadvantage is that `every()` is not intended to be used that way. As you've already figured out, it won't break your code or make your computer explode, it works just fine, the only thing I can think of is just that, it's not how it's supposed to be used. There are many ways to iterate an array, for-in loops work just fine, map, filter, some, every, reduce, reduceRight etc. They all work just fine, it doesn't mean you should use anything other than a regular for loop to iterate an array and break out, or `forEach` if you're going to iterate all the indices.

Answer (score 4):

They have very different purposes. While `forEach` executes a function with side effects (not very functional) for each element and returns nothing, `every` is a functional method to test whether all elements fulfill a given predicate and returns a boolean. Also, `every` does expect a callback that returns a `boolean` - which most `forEach` callbacks dont.

As an example:

```
> [1,2,3].forEach(console.log)
1
2
3
undefined
> [1,2,3].every(console.log)
1
false
```

If you want to use the iteration methods and need to break out, then yes you might abuse `some`/`every`, but that's not what they're made for. Notice that breaking the loop by returning a boolean does not lead to much better readability :-) I'd suggest to use them only when you can make use of the return value, i.e. if you *need* to know whether the loop aborted prematurely.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of any disadvantages here of using every for that? Like if they are slower or something like that compared to forEach. The point here is that compare operations on the iterated objects might be expensive so being able to break out of the loop if some error condition is reached kind of makes sense ;-)

Comment: It's most likely slower than a plain loop, and faster than foreach when you don't iterate all elements. However I think a "comparison" is pointless because of their non equivalent behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `every` is to check if every element of an array meets a test - and it returns true of it is so. `forEach` just runs its argument for each element of the array. So in a sense if your function returns true, every and forEach are equivalent. But it is better to be explicit - if you want to test all elements, use every. If you want to execute a function for each element, use forEach.

Comment: Should you use `every` if you want to execute a function for less than all the elements?

Comment: Yes, you can use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

From this exact question here: [map, foreach and every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340893/what-is-the-difference-between-map-every-and-foreach)

> The difference is in the return values.
>
> [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>   **returns a new Array of objects** created by taking some action on the original item.
>
> [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
>   **returns a boolean** - true if every element in this array satisfies the provided testing function.  An important difference with
>   `.every()` is that the test function may not always be called for
>   every element in the array.  Once the testing function returns false
>   for any element, no more array elements are iterated.  Therefore, the
>   testing function should usually have no [side
>   effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40314/13820).
>
> [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
>   **returns nothing** - It iterates the Array performing a given action for each item in the Array.
>
> **Edit:** Here's the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4h76zbx(VS.94).aspx) if
>   you prefer.

Comment: Isn't there also a difference in performance and early breaking?