# for in loop behaving strangely in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
var friends=['2','3'];
console.log(friends);
var rooms=[];
for(var friend in friends){
var room = 'userid'+friend+'friends';
console.log(room);
rooms.push(room);
}
console.log(rooms);
```

this outputs

```
[ '2', '3' ]
 userid0friends
 userid1friends
 [ 'userid0friends', 'userid1friends' ]
```

3 is neglected entirely, and it behaves even more strangely on my node.js server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`friend` here is the index of your array, not the value at the index

```
var room = 'userid'+friends[friend]+'friends';
```

Plus when looping through an array I don't recommend to use for..in loops, you can use `Array.prototype.map` or plain for loop with the length of your array

### Array map example:

```
var friends=['2','3'];
console.log(friends);
var rooms= friends.map(function (friend, index) {
    return 'userid' + friend + 'friends';
});
console.log(rooms);
```

### Plain for loop:

```
var friends=['2','3'];
console.log(friends);
var rooms=[];
for (var i = 0, l = friends.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var room = 'userid' + friends[i] + 'friends';
    console.log(room);
    rooms.push(room);
}
console.log(rooms);
```

Comment: You are misusing `.map()`.  See [What is the difference between .map, .every, and .forEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340893/what-is-the-difference-between-map-every-and-foreach).

Answer (score 1):

The `for in` structure is used to loop the object, `for key in object`, `key` is the property name of the object, when used for an array, `key` will be the array index.

You could use `.map` to get your result:

```
var friends=['2','3'];

var rooms = friends.map(function(e) {
  return 'userid'+e+'friends';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A for in loop is used to enumerate objects. You are trying to iterate over an array.  A better technique for iterating would be a regular for loop or the `Array.forEach()` method.

In a for in loop, the variable contains the key, not the value.  To get the value, use the key:

```
for(var i in friends){
    var friend = friends[i];
    ...
}
```

But, again, this enumerates an object, including any properties besides the array elements.  This means that if any code adds a method to `Array.prototype`, that method will also be enumerated. Using `.forEach()` is better:

```
friends.forEach(function (friend, i) {
    ...
});
```

Better yet, since you are trying to create a new Array based on the contents of another, use `Array.map()`. That is exactly what it's for.

```
var rooms = friends.map(function (friend, i) {
    return 'userid'+friend+'friends';
});
```