# Is it okay to change the value of an array inside the Array.every, Array.some e.t.c

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The following code works. But is it the right way to modify an array value within the functional-programming styled methods.

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
a.every(function(val,index, arr) {
 if (val === 2) {
    arr[index] += 1;
 }
});
```

Comment: Not really, you probably want `map` not `every`.

Comment: Why not? You can modify array values in `some` and `every`. You can as well delete values, and methods will still work as expected. In fact both methods are designed to support that behavior. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17 However in your example you should not use `every` you should use `map`.

Comment: If you gonna use `map`, `filter`, etc... you might as well avoid mutation, and carry on as I think that's the style it calls for. If I need to "modify" the array and no methods help, then I'd use `reduce` with a brand new accumulator.

Comment: Using a for loop seems pretty legit for this use case, unless you actually need the old version of the array as well. Just saying

Answer (score 1):

No. Though your code works, conceptually you should use the `forEach` method instead, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340893/what-is-the-difference-between-map-every-and-foreach).
<del>(Also, for readability, drop your `arr` argument and use `this`.)</del>

Comment: It depends on the siutation (for this specific example, `map` is the more idiomatic function to use), though in general if you want to edit the array from your function, you're probably better off with `forEach`. Also, `forEach` isn't a jQuery method, so `this` refers to the global object or undefined in strict mode.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, you are absolutely right that `this` can not be used in the callback. I will edit my answer.
I disagree however on using `map` as its intention is to create a new array, which is not what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> But is it the right way to modify an array value within the functional-programming styled methods.

No. With the functional programming paradigm you should not modify any objects (regardless of what method you use). Better:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.map(function(val) {
  return (val === 2) ? 3 : val;
});
```

Notice that using `every` like you did makes no sense - you are not interested in testing a predicate on all elements. When you really want to carry out side-effects from your callback, you should use `forEach` (which is not very functional, but at least makes your intention clear).