# Joi validate order of array

Tags: javascript, joi

I've looked through Joi APIs but there's no such thing as array order. I also looked into Joi `refs` but currently it's impossible (correct me if I'm wrong) to use them inside arrays.

I'm thinking of using `extend` but not sure it's possible to retrieve the whole array.

**Input:**

```
const asc = [1,2,3];
const noOrder = [10,7,8];
const desc = [6,5,4];
```

**Desired output:**

```
Joi.validate(asc, Joi.array().asc()) // True
Joi.validate(asc, Joi.array().desc()) // False
Joi.validate(desc, Joi.array().desc()) // False
Joi.validate(noOrder, Joi.array().desc()) // False
Joi.validate(noOrder, Joi.array().asc()) // True
```

So my question is, how do I get started with this? Any idea is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you tried [array.ordered](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#arrayorderedtype)

Comment: @CodeManiac the problem is the length of the array is variable

Comment: i guess you can extend something similar to how [array.unique](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#arrayuniquecomparator-options) works value and a function

Comment: @CodeManiac perhaps something like `Joi.array().unique((a,b) => a <= b)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joi doesn't offer any built-in way to validate the order of an array so you will have to `extend` with your own extension, like so:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const customJoi = Joi.extend((joi) => ({
  base: joi.array(),
  name: 'array',
  language: {
      asc: 'needs to be sorted in ascending order',
      desc: 'needs to be sorted in descending order'
  },

  rules: [
      {
          name: 'asc',        
          validate(params, value, state, options) { 
            const isAscOrder = value.every((x, i) => i === 0 || x >= value[i - 1]);
            return isAscOrder ? value : this.createError('array.asc', {v: value}, state, options);             
          }
      },
      {
          name: 'desc',          
          validate(params, value, state, options) {
            const isDescOrder = value.every((x, i) => i === 0 || x <= value[i - 1]);
            return isDescOrder ? value : this.createError('array.desc', {v: value}, state, options);             
          }
      }
  ]
}));

const ascSchema = customJoi.array().asc();
const descSchema = customJoi.array().desc();

// Validation results.
console.log(Joi.validate([5, 7, 9, 10], ascSchema)); //true
console.log('\n\n');
console.log(Joi.validate([5, 7, 6, 10], ascSchema)); //false
console.log('\n\n');
console.log(Joi.validate([5, 4, 2, 0], descSchema)); //true
console.log('\n\n');
console.log(Joi.validate([5, 4, 2, 6], descSchema)); //false
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. Quick question would it be more performant to use `forEach()` then `createError` than `every`? Or even a `for` loop?

Comment: You are welcome. `Every` method will stop checking array elements once it finds one element that does not satisfy the condition. You can achieve the same behavior with a `foreach` and `for` loop but you will have to explicitly break the loop, so the solution will be much more verbose. Another good thing about `every` is that the function passed is usually a pure function with no side effects. You can check more about the difference between each array method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340893/what-is-the-difference-between-map-every-and-foreach

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. Accepted the answer

Comment: Cheers @BrianLe! See you around.

Answer (score 1):

[As of v16.0.0](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1885), Joi supports validating the order of an array with the following schema:

```
Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.number())
    .sort({ order: 'ascending' });
```